# Dimension of polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

Suppose I have a polynomial ring $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ and let $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]_m$ denote the homogeneous part with degree $m$. How can I see that this $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]_m$ has dimension $\binom{m+n}{m}$? Or more exactly, why does this give the Krull dimension?

Comment: The monomials are linearly independent, to count them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition

Comment: But is that same as the Krull dimension?

Comment: No. The Krull dimension $=n$ is the idea that we have a chain of $n+1$ prime ideals : $\{0\}\subset (x_0)\subset (x_0,x_1)\subset \ldots \subset (x_0,\ldots,x_n)$. The homogeneous polynomials of degree $m$ are those of the form $f(x)=\sum_{|a|=m} c_a x^a$ (where $x^a=  \prod_j x_j^{a_j}$). Note that $f(x)/x_0^m$ is well-defined as a function on $\Bbb{P}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If you denote $k_i$ the exponent of $xi$in such a monomial, it is the number of solutions in natural numbers of the equation
$$k_0+k_1+\dots+ k_n=m.$$